# Add new item to container with a form using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to add a grid item to a grid container using form input. If anyone has any suggestions it would be very helpful.

This is my code so far :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function addNote(note) {
      childNumber = 1;
      let noteContainer = document.getElementById("grid-container");
      var newNote = '<p>Child' + note + childNumber + '</p>';
      noteContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("test", newNote)
      childNumber++;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <style>
    #note {
      height: 200px;
      font-size: 14pt;
    }
    
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(1, [row] auto);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .grid-item {
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>


  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>


  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Notes</h2>
    <form>
      <label for="Note">Add Note</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="note" name="Note"><br>
      <button onclick="addNote(note)">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. - I created that. Now please elaborate on the problems you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a form, use submit event and stop it from submitting

If not, use a type="button"

Also you did not use the value of the note

I suggest you wrap the note in the div and just append the HTML to the container

```js
let childNumber = 0;
const noteContainer = document.getElementById("grid-container");
const note =  document.getElementById("note");
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission
  var newNote = '<div class="grid-item"><p>Child ' + note.value + childNumber + '</p></div>';
  noteContainer.innerHTML += newNote
  childNumber++;
})
```

```css
#note {
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, [row] auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">



</div>

<div>
  <h2>Notes</h2>
  <form id="myForm">
    <label for="Note">Add Note</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="note" name="Note"><br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```